# Proving properties of sin(x) and cos(x) from differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation

$y'' + y = 0$

and that it's solutions are $s(x)$ and $c(x)$ how can we prove the following 2 properties of the solutions

$s(x+a) = s(x)c(a) + c(x)s(a)$

$c(x+a) = c(x)c(a) - s(x)s(a)$

by only analysing the differential equation and without using any trigonometry.

The solutions $s(x)$ and $c(x)$ are determined by initial conditions

$s(0) = 0$ and $s'(0) = 1$

$c(0) = 1$ and $c'(0) = 0$

Comment: Link it up... The chain rule does the job.

Comment: Certainly it must be that you know something more about $s(x)$ and $c(x)$ than they are solutions: For example, if $c(x) = s(x)$, will your equalities still hold?

Comment: If you add that the solutions satisfy $s(0) = 0, s'(0) = 1$ and $c(0) = 1, c'(0) = 0$, then the proof's not so bad. Without those constraints (or others like them) the claim simply isn't true. Also: if $s$ and $c$ are solutions of a homogeneous diff'l equation, so is $As + Bc$ for any real constants $A$ and $B$, so the the idea that " $s$ and $c$ are its solutions" isn't really even meaningful -- they're just 2 out of infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @JohnHughes, those pesky initial conditions which are ever so important in considering uniqueness...

Comment: Added the initial conditions

Comment: Great -- now that you've edited, you have a reasonable question. What are your thoughts, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: It seems like a trivial problem but I'm having some difficulty coming up with a way to split the left hand side term to obtain the right side

Comment: @user34304 Try to differentiate twice the function $f(x)=s(x+a)-s(x)c(a)-c(x)s(a)$ with respect to $x$, and then use the initial data to see that $f$ must be identically zero.

Answer (score 1):

As $s$ and $c$ are solutions of the differential equation, so is 
$$
f(x)=c(a)s(x)+s(a)c(x)
$$
as a linear combination. For the value and derivative at $x=0$ you get
$$
f(0)=s(a),\;f'(0)=c(a)
$$
If you were to know that $s'(x)=c(x)$ for all $x$, and as $y''+y=0$ is autonomous, you could directly conclude that $f(x)=s(a+x)$.

So what you have to argue is that from $s'(0)=1=c(0)$ and $c'(0)=0=-s(0)$ it follows that these relations hold for all $x$.